# Biopython PDB: get resseq

Tags: python, biopython

I've parsed from a pdb file a list of residues:

```
res_list=PDB.Selection.unfold_entities(Find_chain(par), 'R')
```

(Find_chain is a function that selects the chain I need), and i'm doing a loop on all the residues, calculating a specific factor for every one. But I also need the "resseq" (because, if I understood, it is the number of the residue as reported in the pdb file). If I do

```
for residue in res_list:
   print residue
```

I get

```
<Residue SER het=  resseq=1 icode= >
<Residue GLN het=  resseq=2 icode= >
<Residue ALA het=  resseq=3 icode= >...
```

but I can't find an function to access the number after "resseq". I know I can manipulate the string, but I wonder if there is a Biopython function to get it somehow!!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Residue object have an attribute `segid`, a tuple with *hetflag, resseq and icode* that are passed on creation. So I guess you can access `resseq` with:

```
resseq = residue.segid[1]
```

But the "right" way is probably using `get_full_id` method from the `Entity` object, from which `Residue` inherits:

```
resseq = residue.get_full_id()[3][1]

# OR if you need the chain, model or structure, load all of them to a variable

residue_id = residue.get_full_id()
resseq = residue_id[3][1]
```